# How to select only one category for wordpress custom post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to select only one category for each custom post . I have used "Only One Category" plugin . But it is also working on general post. I only need that only for custom post . Please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can control what to show in the post editor better with http://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/ .Works for both categories and tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can create pages for each post type categories and display it each page

like archive-{post_type}.php

you cam view this page

[click here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)